# SharePoint 2007 x64 workflow with Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sharepoint, workflow, 64-bit

I have development environment with 64-bit SharePoint 2007. I tried to create SharePoint workflow with Visual Studio 2008 and got error message "A 32-bit version of SharePoint Server is not installed. Please install a 32-bit version of SharePoint Server". Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm shortly going to be in a similar scenario and have been looking into this issue ahead of time since I heard of this issue in blog write-ups. You can apparently still develop under 32bit and then move it to the 64bit server.

It seems that the issue is truly in the Sharepoint Extensions...so if you don't use them (ie. SharePoint 2007 Sequential Workflow or SharePoint 2007 State Machine Workflow projects) and [just create a workflow project it appears to have better success for some](http://sharepointsharpener.wordpress.com/2009/01/12/developing-workflows-not-possible-on-64-bit-sharepoint/).(look in the comments to the posting)

[Here's the tracked bug at Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=325668), some VS team members provided a "work around" which is basically what I first mentioned.

Bottom line, crummy handling by Microsoft considering this is their "Showpiece" and they are pushing people to 64bit platform. In another two weeks I should be feeling this, if I come up with anything more I'll post back. Good Luck!

Comment: I have confirmed with MS that the problem is with the templates, which where never meant to be installed on 64 Bit. They were meant to be part of the VseWSS extensions however someone didn't hit the right switch during the VS builds.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, agree with curtisk. I've spent today developing a generic Windows Workflow for SharePoint because I couldn't use the extensions. You lose a bit in the ease of deployment but there are plenty of resources out there on how to do this manually. This worked for me (at least the deployment part of it anyway): -

http://blah.winsmarts.com/2008-7-Authoring_SharePoint_2007_Workflows_using_VS2008.aspx

Note that in my case I was working on a 32bit Windows 2003 VM but hosted on a 64bit Virtual Server.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same problem just now.  I found that STSDEV has the exact project type as an option.

So use [STSDEV](http://www.codeplex.com/stsdev) to create this kind of project.  Since it's broke in 64bit Win2k3 with VseWSS 2008 its best to use STSDEV instead.

Answer (score 0):

We worked around this by designing the workflows in SharePoint designer and then just bundling and then including them in the WSP when deploying through Visual Studio using VseWSS.

PS: SharePoint Designer is now a free product.

Comment: Yes, Designer is free, and if you paid for it (like we had) you're entitled to expression web license instead